# PHP form (using POST) doesn't submit or send email, just shows a blank page

Tags: php

I have the following HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.domain.co.uk/v2/contact.php" id="contactform">
              <p><label for="name"><span class="required">*</span> Your Name</label><br>
              <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" class="input" required> </p>
              <p><label for="email"><span class="required">*</span> Email</label><br>
              <input name="email" type="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="input" required></p>
              <p><label for="phone">Phone</label><br>
              <input name="phone" type="tel" id="phone" size="30" value="" class="input"></p>
              <p><label for="subject">Subject</label><br>
              <select name="subject" id="subject" class="input">
              <option value="Not sure" selected="selected">Not sure</option>
                <option value="this">this</option>
                <option value="that">that</option>
              </select></p>              
              <p><label for="comments"><span class="required">*</span> Message</label><br>
              <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" class="input" required></textarea></p>
              <p><input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></p>
              </form>
```

and the following in contact.php

```
<?php

    if ($_POST['name'] != "") {
    $_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ($_POST['name'] == "") {
        $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/><br/>';
    }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['email'] != "") {
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors .= "$email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/><br/>";
    }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your email address.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['phone'] != "") {
    $_POST['phone'] = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ($_POST['phone'] == "") {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your phone number.<br/>';
    }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your phone number.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['subject'] != "") {
    $_POST['subject'] = filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ($_POST['subject'] == "") {
        $errors .= 'Please choose a subject.<br/>';
    }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please choose a subject.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['comments'] != "") {
    $_POST['comments'] = filter_var($_POST['comments'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ($_POST['comments'] == "") {
        $errors .= 'Please enter a message.<br/>';
    }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter a message.<br/>';
    }


    if (!$errors) {
            $mail_to = 'info@myemails.co.uk';
            $subject = 'Enquiry';
            $message .= 'Regarding: ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n\n";
            $message .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n\n";
            $message .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n";
            $message .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n";
            $message .= 'Message ' . $_POST['comments'] . "\n\n";

            $success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, "From: <$email>");

            if ($success){
              print "sent";
            }
            else{
              print "failed";
            }
    }

?>
```

no matter what I change or try I end up on a blank white page for contact.php instead of seeing the sent or failed message (having removed my javascript validation incase I was causing issue there), likewise there is nothing in the error log and despite having gone back over the code I can't spot the issue? Unsure if I have stared at it for too long and missing something obvious or there is a deeper problem?

Any pointers appreciated.

var_dump shows it is getting the information:

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(10) "Joe Bloggs" ["email"]=> string(16) "joe@anyemail.com" ["phone"]=> string(11) "07123456789" ["subject"]=> string(8) "Not sure" ["comments"]=> string(17) "test message here" }
```

Comment: In case there where errors, your script is not even attempting to send the mail (so you can not expect to see _either_ of the two outputs from within that if branch), and you are not making _any other_ output in that case either (like for example of $errors, to see what went wrong.) Btw., you should properly initialize variables, _before_ you try to append to them. Please go enable proper PHP error reporting (go read up on it, if that doesn’t mean anything to you) first of all now, so that PHP can alert you regarding such mistakes.

Comment: P.S.. You are using `$errors .=` where you define this var ? Same here `$message .=`

Comment: Is that localhost ?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm I have edited post with the results

Comment: @angel.bonev no this is live.

Comment: @user4349555 Did you check my second comment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used string concatenation, but you didn't defined your variables before that, if you change your code, like this:

```
<?php

        $errors = '';

        if ($_POST['name'] != "") {
        $_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['name'] == "") {
                $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/><br/>';
        }
        } else {
                $errors .= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
        }

        if ($_POST['email'] != "") {
        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $errors .= "$email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/><br/>";
        }
        } else {
                $errors .= 'Please enter your email address.<br/>';
        }

        if ($_POST['phone'] != "") {
        $_POST['phone'] = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['phone'] == "") {
                $errors .= 'Please enter your phone number.<br/>';
        }
        } else {
                $errors .= 'Please enter your phone number.<br/>';
        }

        if ($_POST['subject'] != "") {
        $_POST['subject'] = filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['subject'] == "") {
                $errors .= 'Please choose a subject.<br/>';
        }
        } else {
                $errors .= 'Please choose a subject.<br/>';
        }

        if ($_POST['comments'] != "") {
        $_POST['comments'] = filter_var($_POST['comments'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['comments'] == "") {
                $errors .= 'Please enter a message.<br/>';
        }
        } else {
                $errors .= 'Please enter a message.<br/>';
        }

        $message = '';
        if (empty($errors)) {
                        $mail_to = 'info@myemails.co.uk';
                        $subject = 'Enquiry';
                        $message .= 'Regarding: ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n\n";
                        $message .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n\n";
                        $message .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n";
                        $message .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n";
                        $message .= 'Message ' . $_POST['comments'] . "\n\n";

                        $success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, "From: <$email>");

                        if ($success){
                            print "sent";
                        }
                        else{
                            print "failed";
                        }
        } else {
            echo $errors;
        }

?>
```

**It works.** You said that you are at live site, so probably errors are not show up, if you want you can add this lines:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of your php file, to see errors, but clients also would see these errors. You can add IP Check for your IP around them.

Comment: I had gone to define the variables but I used $errors = NULL; is it better to use '' ?

Comment: And may be 

`ini_set("mail.log", "/PATH LOG TO FILE.log");
ini_set("mail.add_x_header", TRUE);`